# Dataframes in nested for loop. <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) error

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

This is a subset of the data frame I am working on:

| ID | FRUIT1 | FRUIT2 | FRUIT3 | VEG1 | VEG2 | VEG3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |

It consists of 5 subjects, for whom there is information on 3 fruits and 3 vegetables:

- 1 = the subject does not eat the fruit/vegetable
- 2 = the subject eats the fruit/vegetable

I am interested in counting how many individuals eat the 9 possible combinations of fruits and vegetables (FRUIT1 with VEG1, FRUIT1 with VEG2, …).
This is the script I wrote:

```
# Read data 
dataframe <- read.csv("myfile.csv", header=TRUE)

# Define variables
FRUIT= names(dataframe)[2:4])
VEG= names(dataframe[5:7]))

# Check frequency of interactions
for (fruit in FRUIT) {
    for (veg in VEG) {
        #Double-positive: keep only subjects that each both the fruit and the vegetable
        PP <- dataframe[dataframe$fruit=='2' & dataframe$veg=='2',]
        #Double-negative: keep only subjects that don’t eat any 
        AA <- dataframe[dataframe$fruit=='1' & dataframe$veg=='1',]
        #Only FRUIT-positive: keep only subjects that eat the fruit, but not the vegetable
        PA <- dataframe[dataframe$fruit=='2' & dataframe$veg=='1',]
        #Only VEG-positive: keep only the subject that eat the vegetable, but not the fruit
        AP <- dataframe[dataframe$fruit=='1' & dataframe$veg=='2',]
        # Print the name of the fruit, the vegetable, and the counts of each of the 4 categories 
    toprint <- c(kir,hla,nrow(PP),nrow(AP),nrow(PA),nrow(AA))
    setwd(“~/Directory/“)
    write(toprint, file = "NumberIndividuals.csv",ncolumns=6,append = TRUE, sep = " ")
    }
}
```

**Problem**: the script above works outside the for loops but in this nested for loops I get the following message: `<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)` for PP, AA, PA and AP.  Why are the sub-datasets (PP, AA, PA and AP) empty in this case?

Comment: you need to do `PP <- dataframe[dataframe[[fruit]] == '2' & dataframe[[veg]] == '2',]` etc, dataframe$fruit is not a column

Comment: There is a closing `)` too much in your calculation of `FRUIT` and `VEG`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change to `PP <- dataframe[dataframe[[fruit]] == '2' & dataframe[[veg]] == '2',]` and the others as well, fruit is a string and dataframe$fruit is not a column

Answer (score 3):

You can try this without explicit `for` loops:

```
combos<-expand.grid(fruit=grep("FRUIT",colnames(dataframe),value=TRUE),
                    veg=grep("VEG",colnames(dataframe),value=TRUE),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
counts<-apply(combos,1,function(x) sum(rowSums(dataframe[,x]==2)==2))
cbind(combos,counts=counts)
#   fruit  veg counts
#1 FRUIT1 VEG1      0
#2 FRUIT2 VEG1      0
#3 FRUIT3 VEG1      0
#4 FRUIT1 VEG2      2
#5 FRUIT2 VEG2      2
#6 FRUIT3 VEG2      3
#7 FRUIT1 VEG3      1
#8 FRUIT2 VEG3      1
#9 FRUIT3 VEG3      2
```